# Am I implementing a generics-based Java factory correctly?

Tags: java, generics, factory-pattern

I don't believe I am implementing the factory pattern correctly because the `Application` class' `createDocument` method accepts any class type, not just subclasses of `Document`.

In other words, is there a way I can restrict the `createDocument` method to only accept subclasses of `Document`?

- Document.java

  ```
  package com.example.factory;

  public abstract class Document {
      public Document() {
          System.out.println("New Document instance created: " + this.toString());
      }
  }
  ```
- DrawingDocument.java

  ```
  package com.example.factory

  public class DrawingDocument extends Document {
      public DrawingDocument() {
          System.out.println("New DrawingDocument instance created: " this.toString());
      }
  }
  ```
- Application.java

  ```
  package com.example.factory;

  public class Application {
      public <T> T createDocument(Class<T> documentClass) {
          try {
              return documentClass.newInstance();
          } catch (InstantiationException e) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
          }
      };
  }
  ```
- Main.java

  ```
  package com.example.factory;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Application application = new Application();
      application.createDocument(DrawingDocument.class);
  }
  ```

Comment: any reason to believe why you're not?

Comment: You're returning a new instance and then immediately ignoring it. Is that intentional?

Comment: As I'm logging the instance creation, I assume the document would be used but in this example I have no need for it.

Comment: What is your motivation for this? Why do you need a factory? From the code you have posted I can't see any advantage compared to using the constructor of the document class directly. Will the application create instances of subclasses of the given class at some later point or will it have to do extensive initialization?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should [bound](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) your generic so that it is only using T's that inherit Document.
example:

```
public class Application {
    //Add extends Document after T
    public static <T extends Document> T createDocument(Class<T> documentClass) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return documentClass.newInstance();
    };
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, just what I was looking for! Apparently I need to wait three minutes to accept your answer, but I will do so once I am able.

Answer (score 6):

The code looks good. In a real implementation the factory method should not be declared to throw any of the reflection-related exceptions. And you will probably have some different code anyway to create the document.

The faxtory method should take a `Class<? extends Document>` as its parameter, so that one cannot ask it to create a `String`, for example.

[update:] Code sample:

```
public Document createDocument(Class<? extends Document> clazz) {
  try {
    return clazz.newInstance();
  } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you propose the try/catch block in the factory method?

Comment: Yes, that would be good. You could encapsulate such an exception in an `IllegalArgumentException` and throw that instead.

Comment: Hmm... how would I go about implementing that refactoring? The try block would surround the return statement... :S

Comment: Ah, so you're saying throw the `IllegalArgumentException` if the return throws the reflection exceptions?

Comment: That code update you did... I'm wondering if my initial approach was better. Does this not require a cast from Document for subclasses? I have the following now: http://snipt.org/xPpp

Comment: By the way, it was completely intentional that I didn't catch `Exception` but only `InstantiationException`. That way, any individual exceptions that might be thrown by the constructors themselves would be preserved as such.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I changed my code to catch the `InstatiationException` and the `IllegalAccessException` exceptions explicitly (updated my snippet).

Answer (score 3):

Where is the restriction to Document type in the factory ? Try

```
public <T extends Document> T createDocument(Class<T> documentClass) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return documentClass.newInstance();
};
```